# Creating a variable sized array of class objects, no default constructor

Tags: c++, arrays

I've spent all morning in my CS tutoring lab and they have been no help so I'm hoping someone out there can nudge me forward. I have to use this class.

```
#ifndef WORD_H
#define WORD_D
#include <iostream>

class Word
{
private:
char* ptr_;
int len_;

public:
Word(const char* word);
~Word();
char GetFirstLetterLower();
char* GetWord();
};


#endif WORD_H
```

I already created a pointer array that will store the pointers of another array.

```
g_wordArray = new Word *[g_arrSz];   
//g_arrSz is the length all arrays need to be
```

now i need to create a second array of Word class that is G_aarSz in length.

the tutor keeps trying to get me to use

```
Word secondArray[g_arrSz];
```

but that doesn't work because the length isn't a constant.

I also tried this

```
Word* secondArray = new int[g_arrSz];
```

but no luck.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: You're right, it shouldn't be `Word secondArray[g_arrSz];`. But why do you then create `new int[g_arrSz];`?

Comment: As you noted, `Word` doesn't have a default constructor. So, how do you imagine creating several of them at once is supposed to work? How is each going to be initialized? Now, if you do add a default constructor, then you can write `Word* words = new Word[g_arrSz];`, or better still, `std::vector<Word> words(g_arrSz);`

Comment: The assignment doesn't allow for a default constructor.

Comment: Even if the length was a constant, `Word secondArray[g_arrSz];` would not work because there is no default constructor. Maybe there is a miscommunication somewhere between you and the tutor.

Answer (score 0):

You were almost there. What you need to do is create a array, but of Word not of int.

So instead of

```
Word* secondArray = new int[g_arrSz];
```

You need to do:

```
Word* secondArray = new Word[g_arrSz];
```

Doing that kind of old-school array is generally a bad idea though, and unless this is for a learning example or for some specific cases, you should use std containers to create your array. Take a look at std::vector or std::array for example. Using vector, you could declare your Word array like this :

```
std::vector<Word> secondArray(g_arrSz);
```

Comment: I tried the second one                                                                             Word* secondArray = new Word[g_arrSz];  and it says "no default constructor exists for class Word"        PS - Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

You can create a vector of objects with no default constructor - obviously you can't fill it with default constructed objects though.

For example:

```
std::vector<Word> words;
for (int i = 0; i < g_arrSz; ++i)
    words.emplace_back("bob");
```